# Angular on AWS EC2: connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm deploying an Angular project onto AWS EC2, which uses a Rails API on a separate instance. and am running into errors with what I presume to be NGINX. (502 Bad Gateway). My error logs read:

```
2018/09/07 22:00:38 [error] 12184#12184: *5 
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while 
connecting to upstream, client: 172.xx.xx.xxx, 
server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"http://172.xx.xx.xx:4200/", host: "xx.xx.xxx.xx"

2018/09/07 22:00:38 [error] 12184#12184: *5 
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while 
connecting to upstream, client: 172.xx.xx.xxx, 
server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "http://172.xx.xx.xx:4200/favicon.ico", 
host: "xx.xxx.xx.xx", referrer: 
"http://54.xx.xx.xx/"
```

I'm wondering what I might have configured wrong. The config file looks like:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
     proxy_pass http://172.xx.xx.xx:4200;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}
```

Does anything need to change in this file because the project is calling to an external API?

In my Angular project I have the API referenced like:

app.module.ts

```
providers: [ ... ,
    {provide: 'api', useValue: 'https://myAPI.com'}]
```

and in environments.ts:

```
token_auth_config: { 
    apiBase: 'https://myAPI.com'

}
```

Let me know if there's anything I can clarify or information I can add! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Can you hit the rails URL from outside of EC2, such as using Postman? And does your EC2 security group allow outbound connections?

Comment: Yep it does hit outside of EC2. Not sure about the outbound connections but I think it does. Under 'outbound rules' it look like it allows all ports.  I'm not even hitting my Angular app in the browser, would any outbound configuration affect that?

Comment: Well it looks like it's trying to make an outbound connection to `http://172.xx.xx.xx:4200/`

Comment: @user184994 that makes sense, should I direct it to my API address instead, which is where my server is?

Comment: I'm hoping for a solution to this as well. Although my Angular app seems to be working fine, and these log entries aren't preventing anything from working right, I don't see anything in my node.js code that would utilize this, and it bothers me that something is making these calls with some verbosity. Will follow this thread and let you know if I find anything...